Is it posible to intensify an adjective + noun using "so" or "very"?
I was wondering if it is possible to intensify an adjective plus a noun using the common intensifiers for adjectives only such as "very" or "so". According to grammar, if intensification of noun or adjective  plus noun is needed, the common intensifier to use is "such a" or "such". I have seen some examples where people use "very" in such circumstances. Can anyone help me please?
For example:
It is a very good day vs it is such a good day.

Could you give 1-3 examples of the type of phrase you are asking about? That will help people understand your question clearly :)

Yes and no. "That's a very big bird" or "that bird is so big" = ok. "The very big bird flew past" = ok. "The so big bird" = not ok. "That bird is so very big" = ok. "The so very big bird" = not ok. Please edit to focus a bit more on one word or other and the context and sentence order you need.

@AndyBonner "The oh-so very big bird" = ok

You wrote "The latter asked due to grammar, if intensification of noun or adjective plus noun is needed, the common intensifier to use is "such a" or "such". I have seen some examples where people utilize "very" in this kind of circumstances."  I think your meaning would have been more clearly expressed had you, instead, written, "I ask about the word "so" because the intensifiers "such a" or "such" would be less surprising to me."  If this suggested modification does not capture your meaning, then I do not understand what you do mean.

Using "very" is no problem. Using "so" is a little more complicated.
Let's use a typical adjective + noun pairing like "hot day" as our example. "It was a very hot day." is a normal, well-constructed sentence. "It was such a hot day." is also normal. This sentence can be expanded upon using "such...that", but the first sentence cannot.
"It was a very hot day that I took my shirt off." (Incorrect)
"It was such a hot day that I took my shirt off." (Correct)
You cannot use "so" in exactly the same way. "It was so hot." is grammatically correct, but "It was a so hot day." is wrong.
Placing the article after the adjective makes it correct: "It was so hot a day." And you're even able to use "that" like I did above. "It was so hot a day that I took my shirt off." But this is a noticeably unusual way of speaking. Most native speakers (in America, anyway) prefer not to phrase a sentence this way when speaking conversationally unless they are trying to sound different or dramatic. It is a little bit more common in formal writing.
